# how to convert a JSON-String to multiple Structs in Julia

Tags: json, string, struct, julia

I have the following JSON-String:

```
jsonString="""{
"struct1": {
    "arg1": 218650.27,
    "arg2": 90
},
"struct2": {
    "arg1": 346.4
}
}"""
```

I know already how to convert a JSON-String to a struct, but not a multiple struct like the JSON File above.
Is there any Pkg that helps in this case, or I have to split the JSON file?

Comment: I haven't heard of multiple struct before. What is it? Did you try: `using JSON; JSON.parse(yourstring)`?

Comment: Why not read it into a `Dict` and then get the structs out using `values(dict)`

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your terminology. Structs are composite types, you don't create them at runtime from a string, but at compile time from code. You should almost certainly create a `Dict`, which is what `JSON.parse` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse JSON to get a dictionary of objects using `JSON3`:

```
julia> u = JSON3.read_json_str(jsonString)
JSON3.Object{Base.CodeUnits{UInt8, String}, Vector{UInt64}} with 2 entries:
  :struct1 => {…
  :struct2 => {…

julia> keys(u)
KeySet for a JSON3.Object{Base.CodeUnits{UInt8, String}, Vector{UInt64}} with 2 entries. Keys:
  :struct1
  :struct2
```

Than each element can be read as a separate `Dict` (here I cast it to `Dict` for readibility):

```
julia> Dict(u[:struct2])
Dict{Symbol, Any} with 1 entry:
  :arg1 => 346.4

julia> Dict(u[:struct1])
Dict{Symbol, Any} with 2 entries:
  :arg1 => 2.1865e5
  :arg2 => 90
```

Now suppose you have a dedicated Julia `struct` to fill-in with those values such as:

```
Base.@kwdef struct MyStruct
    arg1::Float64 = 0.0
    arg2::Int = 0
end
```

If you now want to store your JSON in such struct you can do:

```
julia> [MyStruct(;u[key]...) for key in keys(u)]
2-element Vector{MyStruct}:
 MyStruct(218650.27, 90)
 MyStruct(346.4, 0)
```